# i tried to run the following query but it shows syntax error

Tags: syntax

i tried to run the following query but it shows syntax error

```
CREATE TABLE books 
(
    book_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    author_fname VARCHAR(100),
    author_lname VARCHAR(100),
    released_year INT,
    stock_quantity INT,
    pages INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(book_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What languange are you using?  That looks correct for mySQL if using SQL it's:

```
    CREATE TABLE books 
(
    book_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    author_fname VARCHAR(100),
    author_lname VARCHAR(100),
    released_year INT,
    stock_quantity INT,
    pages INT
);
```